# How to style checkbox mark with cell selection enabled

Tags: javafx-8

I am having an issue I can't seem to find the correct CSS to correct.  When I use the checkbox table cell and and select the row the checkbox mark goes white - looking like it's deselected.

[image]

I was able to change my CSS so that this appears the same either selected or not.

```
.table-row-cell:selected > .check-box-table-cell > .check-box:selected > .box > .mark {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

[image]

However if that table switches to Cell Selection - then this CSS doesn't work.

[image]

I have tried to change adding this as a style:

```
.table-cell:selected > .check-box-table-cell > .check-box:selected > .box > .mark {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

But that leaves me with the same styling as noted above.  Not sure how to keep that checkbox from going whited while cell selection is true.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your css code I couldn't exactly reproduce your pictures, since your posted css only changes the appearance of the mark and you probably have extra css code changing the appearance of the check-box, but the problem seems to lie in the css referencing.

.table-cell:selected already refers to the check-box-table-cell, so try

```
.table-cell:selected > .check-box:selected > .box > .mark{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

or

```
.check-box-table-cell:selected > .check-box:selected > .box > .mark{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```